# iOS load UIWebView URL from notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, apple-push-notifications, apn

I'm having a strange issue, using Xcode 5 and testing on iOS 7, I'm sending an extra parameter with the apn request named "url", I need to open that URL in the webview when the notification is received, but the app freeze when the notification arrives if it was connected to the USB, or does nothing when is not connected.

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Did Register for Remote Notifications with Device Token (%@)", deviceToken);
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Did Fail to Register for Remote Notifications");
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", error, error.localizedDescription);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Register for Remote Notifications
    [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
        // Launched from push notification
        NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
        NSLog(@"Notification received");
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        // app was already in the foreground
        NSLog(@"app was already in the foreground");
    } else {
        // app was just brought from background to foreground
        NSLog(@"app was just brought from background to foreground");
    }

    if ([userInfo objectForKey:@"url"])
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"loadNotificationUrl" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
    }
}
```

And that's what is in the ViewerController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *urlString = @"http://example.com/?action=home";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];

    webView.delegate = self;
    webView.opaque = NO;
    webView=[[UIWebView alloc]init];
    [webView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    [webView setDelegate:(id<UIWebViewDelegate>)self];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];

    activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(200.0, 200.0, 100.0, 40.0);
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview: activityIndicator];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(loadNotificationUrl:)
                                                 name:@"loadNotificationUrl" object:nil];
}

-(void)loadNotificationUrl:(NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSDictionary* userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    NSString* NotificationUrl = (NSString*)userInfo[@"url"];
    NSLog (@"Successfully received: %@", NotificationUrl);

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:NotificationUrl];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
}
```

As my little experience, this should load the URL when the notification is clicked, but it is either freeze or does nothing, can anybody tell me where is my mistake please?

Comment: Can you post your log?

Comment: When the phone is connected to xcode, the app and the log freeze after receiving the notification, and `didReceiveRemoteNotification` is never called, but when I unplug the device and test the app, everything works great, as i put an **UIAlertView** in the `loadNotificationUrl` to check if the new URL is extracted well from the notification, and that worked! but the webview doesn't load it.

Comment: I fixed half of the problem, app & log not freezing anymore and the url is being retrived, but it is not being loaded in the webview:

`UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (notification) {
        NSLog(@"app received a notification %@",notification);
        [self application:application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)notification];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"app did not receive a notification");
    }`

Comment: Here is the log now:

Before the notification:

`[962:60b] app did not receive a notification

[962:60b] Did Register for Remote Notifications with Device Token (<xxxxxx>)

[962:60b] Starting: (null)

[962:60b] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x16dd7a00 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://old-example.com/?action=home, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://old-example.com/?action=home}

[962:60b] Starting: (null)

[962:60b] Finished: (null)`

Comment: The log after the notification is received with the new URL:

`[962:60b] app was already in the foreground

[962:60b] Successfully received: http://example.com

[962:60b] Starting: 

[962:60b] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1849f370 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://example.com/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://example.com/}

[962:60b] Starting: 

[962:60b] Finished: http://example.com/?session=4e6b9e9d32f8e7`